# How to set editor's height and populate at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

Sorry for this really simple question.

I can use this to set the initial height of the editor:

```
$('#content').summernote({height: 300,});
```

And i can use this to populate the editor:

```
$('#content').summernote('code',content);
```

I want to use both of them at the same time but i can't make it work. Simply using one after another doesn't work. And i don't know how to use them both in one line. For example this doesn't work:

```
$('#content').summernote('code',content,{height:300});
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to initialize the editor with data in one instruction.

If you want it on one line and not exactly one instruction you can do

```
$('#content').summernote({height: 300}).summernote('code',content);
```

Or you can simply put your content in the element before initializing the editor

```
$('#content').html(content).summernote({height: 300});
```